# How to retrive data from document directory when application start?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I have created application that record sound and display that sound file in `tableview`. In that application when sound is recorded than it's `filepath` will store in a array , which array i use to populate my `tableview`. But my problem is that when i close the application then my array will be empty , and i lost my recorded file.

So now how can i get my recorded file when i open my app second time. I am storing sound file in document directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store array in `NSUserDefaults`. Retrive and Store the array in `NSUserDefaults`  .. see the example of `NSUserDefaults`

In `AppDelegate.h` file just declare variable...

```
    NSUserDefaults  *userDefaults;
    NSMutableArray *yourArray;
    after...
```

In `AppDelegate.m` Fille in `applicationDidFinishLonching:` Method

```
    userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"yourArray"];
    if (dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch != nil) {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
            yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [yourArray retain];
```

after that when you want to insert Data in this `UserDefaults` Use Bellow Code...

```
    [appDelegate.yourArray addObject:yourDataString];///set your value or anything which you want to store here...
    NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appDelegate.yourArray];
    [appDelegate.userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"yourArray"];
    [appDelegate.userDefaults synchronize];
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: Is your codes last segment is for update the available data in our userDefults ?

Comment: yes plist is also for this use .. but i use userdefault bcoz some time plist file may be not useful to much so..